# How to get two factor authentication when resetting password and no devices configured for two factor

Tags: github, two-factor-authentication

I recently wanted to use one of my old project specific GitHub account, where the two factor authentication was enabled. Since I was not able to remember the password I used the option Forgot password and reset the password.

However after successfully changing the credentials, GitHub is as usual expecting the two way authentication key, since I was not having the same device now, I don't have the GitHub configured to get the Two way authentication, neither I have any more information about the account, rather than my login credentials.

Is there any way I could get the two - way refactor working. Or I could login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If have the credential of the GitHub account, you can login to said account, and [enable 2FA](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-two-factor-authentication-via-a-totp-mobile-app/)

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/2fa/2fa-settings.png]

Then you can [generate a PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/) in order to use that as a password (and bypass the 2fa step when pushing in command-line).

> Personal access tokens are useful when it's too cumbersome to provide a client/secret pair for a full application, such as when authenticating to GitHub from Git using HTTPS, or within a command line utility or script.

---

> Later I reset my password , and I was't having the device which i had configured my DuO Mobile. How could I login now. It is asking for 2FA and I don't have any way to provide the key.

Then you would need to follow "[Recovering your account if you lost your 2FA credentials](https://help.github.com/articles/recovering-your-account-if-you-lost-your-2fa-credentials/)"

> Having access to your recovery codes in a secure place, or establishing a secondary mobile phone number for recovery, will get you back into your account.

Comment: Hi Vonc I think my question was I already enabled this functionality, and I used in my device Duo Mobile to generate 2FA. Later I reset my password , and I was't having the device which i had configured my DuO Mobile. How could I login now. It is asking for 2FA and I don't have any way to provide the key. Until unless I configure it from first. Thanks

Comment: @TBA I have edited the answer, but you would need recovery code, or a mobile phone number registered with that 2FA.

Comment: There is no other way I could get the details without recovery code, Fortunately I got my old device back and get this working... But I would like to see any other way it is possible, so keep it open with a bounty, Thanks @VonC , I think there may not be any other way to do this.

Comment: @TBA I usually connect to my mobile device with adb, and export the 2FA TOTP (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm) secret key from the sql database

Comment: @TBA would that procedure (extraction of the secret key from the mobile device) be of interest here for you?

Comment: Thanks VonC, at the end there is only one way we could recover it by saving the recovery options securely.

Comment: @TBA still, do you know that, beside the recovery options, you can extract the secret key itself?

Comment: Sorry I am not aware of it, How could we achieve it?

Comment: @TBA Then `shell@android:/ $ sqlite3 /data/data/com.google.android.apps.authenticator2/databases/databases`, `select * from accounts;`